# Flutter : Schema validation: Incompatible types

Tags: flutter, dependencies, pubspec

This is my pubsepc.yaml. All I'm trying to do is use different font formats

```
fonts:
    - family: Schyler
      fonts:
        - asset: fonts/Schyler-Regular.ttf
        - asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf
          style: italic
    - family: Trajan Pro
      fonts:
        - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
        - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
          weight: 700
```

For which, I get this error :

```
  Schema validation: Incompatible types.
  Required one of: null, object, string. Actual: array.
```

Please help

Comment: can you please post the Screen Shot of expanded fonts folder ?

Comment: You sure you have the right spacing? There should be double spaces before the first 'fonts:'